# How to add a column of seconds to a column of times in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time, addition, timedelta

I have a file contain some columns which the second column is time. Like what I show below. I need to add a column of time which all are in seconds like this: "2.13266      2.21784      2.20719      2.02499      2.16543", to the time column in the first file (below). My question is how to add these two time to each other. And maybe in some cases when I add these times, then it goes to next day, and in this case how to change the date in related row.

2014-08-26 19:49:32  0
2014-08-28 05:43:21  0
2014-08-30 11:47:54  0
2014-08-30 03:26:10  0

Comment: use pandas datetime frame and add Timedelta(seconds=value)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to read your file into a pandas data-frame and parse each row as a `datetime` object. Then you create a `datetime.timedelta` object passing the fractional seconds.

A `datetime` object + a `timedelta` handles wrapping around for days quite nicely so this should work without any additional code. Finally, write back your updated dataframe to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your datetime field is an actual date time (if reading from csv it won't be).

```
df['DateTimeField'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTimeField'])
```

Then, convert your column of seconds to a time delta column and add to the date time field

```
df['NewDateTimeField'] = df['DateTimeField'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['TimeDeltaField'], unit='s')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally it is done via this code:
    `d= 2.13266`
    `dd= pd.to_timedelta (int(d), unit='s')`
    `df= pd.Timestamp('2014-08-26 19:49:32')`
    `new = df + dd`